# Let $(N,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space. If $\dim{N}<\infty$ then every Cauchy sequence of $N$ converges.

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I saw the proof ot the result that says that $(\mathbb{R}^{n},\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ is Banach. The question above can be solved following the same idea?

Comment: Under the assumption that a "normed spaced" means a vector space over either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ with a norm, then $N$ being finite dimensional means that $N$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ for some $n$.  These are complete with respect to any of the usual norms (i.e. any $L^p$-norm; $p=2$ is the Euclidean norm, $p=1$ is the taxicab norm, etc).  If you mean something more general, such as a vector space over some other field, things get more complicated.  For example, $\mathbb{Q}$ can be seen as a 1-dimensional vector space with norm $|\cdot|$, but is not complete.

Comment: My idea: Because $N$ is a normed space with $\dim{N}<\infty$ we take $\{v_{1},...,v_{n}\}$ base for $N$ ($n=\dim{N}$), i can take a point $x\in N$ and write $$x=\sum_{j=1}^{n}{x_{j}v_{j}}$$ with $x_{j}\in\Re$. The we procede "treating" $N$ as $\Re^{n}$.

Comment: All right, except you are treating $N$ as $\color{green}{\mathbf{\mathbb R}}^n$, and not ${\color{red}{\mathbb Q}}^n$, for example. The completeness of the *field* under the given norm matters in this question.

Comment: Again, if $N$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, then $N$ **is** (for all meaningful intents and purposes) $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$---this is a fairly basic result.  But you are assuming that the underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$.  What if it is $\mathbb{Q}$?  Do you allow that in your definition of a normed space?

Comment: In that case, you must inform your teacher that the underlying field of the vector space matters in this question. In particular, if the underlying field is complete under the norm, so is the vector space, through this argument of treating the vector space $V$ like $\mathbb F^n$. But for $\mathbb F = \mathbb R,\mathbb C$, your argument works out, and that may suffice for your teacher.

Comment: Your entire question comes down to understanding what the base field is.  If you don't know that, I don't see how the question can be answered...

Comment: Yes, i understand the concepts of fileld, basis, vector space over a field, etc. This is the first time i'm studyin analysys in metric spaces ($\Re^{n},n>1$), so this is all new to me. I was just with de doubt if i can consider $N$ as $(anyfield)^{n}$. And my teacher confirmed today that i can use this idea and all ideas you guys has commented above. Tnanks a lot! :)